# Docker Stack Swarm - Service Replicas are not spread for Mutli Service Stack

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I  have deployed a stack with a of 4 services on two hosts (docker compose version 3). 
The services are Elasticsearch, Kibana. Redis, Visualiser and finally my Web App. I have't set any resource restrictions yet.
I spun two virtual host via docker-machine , one with 2GB and one with 1GB.
Then I increased the replicas of my web app to 2 replicas, which resolved to the following distribution:

*Host1 (Master):*
Kibana, Redis, **Web App**, Visualiser, **WebApp**

*Host2 (Worker):*
Elasticsearch

Why is the Swarm Manager distributing both **Web App** Containers to the same host. Wouldn't it be smarter if Web App is distributed to both hosts? 
Besides node tagging I couldn't find any other way in the docs to influence the distribution.
Am I missing something?

Thanks

Bjorn

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: "3"
services:
  visualizer:
    image: dockersamples/visualizer:stable
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    networks:
      - webnet

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.3
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xms1g -Xmx1g
    ulimits:
      memlock: -1
      nofile:
        hard: 65536
        soft: 65536
      nproc: 65538
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.5"
          memory: 1g
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    networks:
      - webnet


  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: bjng/workinseason:swarm
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "80:6000"
    networks:
      - webnet

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:5.4.3
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - webnet

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    networks:
      - webnet



volumes:
  esdata:
    driver: local


networks:
  webnet:
```

Comment: Please include your docker-compose.yml file and your version of docker.

Comment: @BMitch
Thank you, I've edited my post with the docker-compose.yml
My version is 
`Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87`

Comment: First guess is the 1g memory limit on elastic used up the host limit on the worker. Second guess is that you may have built the image locally with a sha256 that the worker can't pull from the registry (with 17.06 this no longer happens with another flag). My initial guesses were that you had an older version of Docker that would count other containers on the host, or that you had a constraint on the web app to run on the manager, but neither of those are the case for you.

Comment: I was thinking that elasticsearch uses a lot of memory as well, will see what happens when I flag elasticsearch for masters only. Thanks anyway so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker schedules tasks (containers) based on available resources; if two nodes have enough resources, the container can be scheduled on either one.

Recent versions of Docker use "HA" scheduling by default, which means that tasks for the same service are spread over multiple nodes, if possible (see this pull request) https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/pull/1446

Comment: Thanks @thaJeztah. Both my hosts have enough resources I would say. My Docker version is 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87, which is I think at this time the latest community version.  So if I understand you correctly, my Web App should be spread ofter two hosts, but its not.

Comment: thats not true. if you will create 2 different services with 2 nodes in most cases they will be placed on the same node

Comment: @AndreyNikishaev it will attempt to spread instances of the _same service_ over available nodes. And, no, there's no _guarantee_ that will happen, so they might still land on the same node. Docker 19.03 and up have a new option to specify the maximum number of instances on a node (see https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/1612), which can be used in situations where running multiple instances on the same node should be prevented.

Comment: @thaJeztah to spread different services around all free nodes i was pushed to use resource reservation thus force for example spread containers so each one have 1 cpu reserver. that was the only way.
For same service there is --max-replicas-per-node parameter, but i didn't find it for compose file (

Comment: It's supported in compose file, schema (version) 3.8 and up; https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/1410. It's not in the docs yet, because docker compose (standalone) does not yet support version 3.8